# IE8 CSS rule "canibalism"?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

This one is going to be very specific I guess... My CSS works flawlessly on all browsers exept IE8. EI10's IE8 emulation does not reflect this bug.

Here is my CSS line that causes problem:

```css
.flag{
    display:block;
    width:24px;
    height:16px;
    background-image:url('../img/flags_sprite.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:0 0;
}
```

Note that this CSS part is condensed on a single line in production like so:

```css
.flag{display:block;width:24px;height:16px;background-image:url("../img/flags_sprite.png");background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:0 0}
```

The width is not taken into consideration by the browser, when inspecting the Styles parsed by the browser I can see this:

```css
.flag
    background-image: url(../img/flags_sprite.png); WIDTH: 24px
    display: block
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    background-position: 0px 0px
    height: 16px
```

Notice that the width is lost as it is treated as part of the background-image declaration. I am mesmerized by this, seeing that the width declaration is textually before the background-image in the CSS file...

What are my options here?

Comment: Have you tried double quotes for url instead of single quotes?

Comment: _“Note that this CSS part is condensed on a single line in production.”_ – so what exactly does that look like then?

Comment: Is this only an issue in the (less than awesome) dev tools, or is it actually causing a rendering problem? Have you tried re-ordering the properties to see if it changes anything?

Comment: @Lolo good try, but no change.

Comment: @OllyHodgson It causes rendering problems... What I see on the dev tool would explain why my element does not have a width

Comment: @Salketer I have added another solution to my answer

Comment: You for got your semi-colons & you shouldn't be developing for IE, as long as it's good on the latest version your fine.

Comment: @brandonjordan You do not know what website I am working on, how can you say I shouldn't dev for IE? 90% of my users are on IE8...

Comment: I would go with @Lolo answer

Comment: @brandonjordan lol of course! then SAP would stop working on their machines... Which is a big no no.

Comment: @Salketer I figured out, that defining all background-xxx properties also helps with that. I have modified my answer again.

Comment: Salketer, thanks very much for asking this.  Anyone making use of Font Awesome,  can expect to see complete CSS havoc in IE8 due to this bug without the fixes below due to the many quoted values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I saw that some time ago, solution that worked for me was to write background definition in single line:

```
background: url("../img/flags_sprite.png") no-repeat 0 0;
```

Another idea is to split definition of `.flag` into 2 parts, also works for me:

```
.flag{
    display:block;
    width:24px;
    height:16px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0px 0px;
}
.flag{
    background-image:url('../img/flags_sprite.png');
}
```

Another solution I ran into is to define all 5 background-xxx properties (-color, -image, -repeat, -position, -attachment). Lack of any cause problem. Example:

```
.flag{
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image:url('../img/flags_sprite.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    display:block;
    width:24px;
    height:16px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked when defining the property on one line. Could not test the second method on the same environment as the CSS optimizer was combining it in one and generating the same code.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Using Font Awesome, so a lot of quotes for unicode characters and font name.  The entire UI was obliterated at times.  Life saver.

Comment: It appears that if only the first rule in a rule set has a value with quotes, the bug does not occur.